# Houdini crashes on start

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, crash

Unable to start Houdini on Windows 10 Home and Nvidia GeForce 770 because of a crash.

Crash Window says:

> Houdini Console 7272: Fatal error: Segmentation fault  Saving
>   application data to ....hipnc

Inside the crash log there is a text

```
Crash report from Соня; Houdini FX Version 17.0.352 [windows-x86_64-cl19.15]
Uptime 0 seconds
Fri Nov 30 17:20:18 2018
Caught signal 11

Traceback from 4620 ThreadId=0x000003d8
CURRENT THREAD 984
+0x78640819 [clGetKernelSubGroupInfoKHR] C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_250db833a1cd577e\igdrclneo64.dll
+0x7862c4a7 C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_250db833a1cd577e\igdrclneo64.dll
+0x7867ceda [clGetKernelSubGroupInfoKHR] C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_250db833a1cd577e\igdrclneo64.dll
+0x7862d10e [clGetPlatformIDs] C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_250db833a1cd577e\igdrclneo64.dll
+0x786341e9 [clEnqueueTask] C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_250db833a1cd577e\igdrclneo64.dll
+0x88e432b5 [clEnqueueWriteBufferRect] C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_250db833a1cd577e\IntelOpenCL64.dll
+0x88e0c85b [clEnqueueWriteBufferRect] C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_250db833a1cd577e\IntelOpenCL64.dll
+0xd0ea10c8 C:\Program Files\Side Effects Software\Houdini 17.0.352\bin\OpenCL.dll
+0xd0ea302b [clWaitForEvents] C:\Program Files\Side Effects Software\Houdini 17.0.352\bin\OpenCL.dll
+0xd0ea293c [clGetPlatformIDs] C:\Program Files\Side Effects Software\Houdini 17.0.352\bin\OpenCL.dll
+0x230fc18a [cl::Platform::get] C:\Program Files\Side Effects Software\Houdini 17.0.352\bin\libCE.dll
+0x230fdba2 [CE_Context::getDevices] C:\Program Files\Side Effects Software\Houdini 17.0.352\bin\libCE.dll
+0x10765f32 [FUSE_PrefDialog::setOpenCLDevice] C:\Program Files\Side Effects Software\Houdini 17.0.352\bin\libFUSE.dll
+0x106d67f6 [FUSE_App::restoreApplicationState] C:\Program Files\Side Effects Software\Houdini 17.0.352\bin\libFUSE.dll
+0x106d33eb [FUSE_App::initApplication] C:\Program Files\Side Effects Software\Houdini 17.0.352\bin\libFUSE.dll
+0x10ca1be0 [OPUI_MainApp::initApplication] C:\Program Files\Side Effects Software\Houdini 17.0.352\bin\libOPUI.dll
+0x109bc7b5 [AP_Interface::loadWindowGeometry] C:\Program Files\Side Effects Software\Houdini 17.0.352\bin\libSI.dll
+0x109bd25d [myWinMain] C:\Program Files\Side Effects Software\Houdini 17.0.352\bin\libSI.dll
+0x40001b9a C:\Program Files\Side Effects Software\Houdini 17.0.352\bin\houdini.exe
+0xe7be3034 [BaseThreadInitThunk] C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
+0xe8661471 [RtlUserThreadStart] C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
```

`igdrclneo64.dll` points to Intel Graphics, which is present in the system, but the monitor is plugged into discrete NVidia card.

What can be the reason?

Comment: Have you tried simply uninstalling the Intel drivers?

Answer (score 1):

I contacted with Houdini dev.

Email:

> It looks like you have an Intel OpenCL driver installed and somehow this driver is corrupted and causing a crash as soon as it gets queried or loaded in any way.
>
> Some laptops come with Intel HD graphics as the default, low-end graphics adapter, and also an NVIDIA card for performance graphics
>
> To temporarily disable the OpenCL driver, you can try running regedit and editing the Windows registry. I believe the key you're looking for is: SOFTWAREKhronosOpenCLVendors. Within that there should be keys for the NVIDIA driver and the Intel driver. If you remove the Intel key that should mean that the faulty Intel OpenCl driver won't try to load.

I followed the way that delete Intel key. And It worked.

May it help you.

Sorry about by bad English.

Comment: Wow, thank you! But the hypothesis that driver is corrupted implies to reinstall it, not disable?

Comment: I had same problem like you. Even the crash log is same. Intel HD graphics shouldn't installed in my computer, but somehow IT did.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to permanently remove the Intel HD graphics? Also would this leave the system in a corrupt state if at a later time I'd remove the Nvidia card?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that the onboard Intel graphics drivers had not been updated for a long time, as when I installed an additional PCIe graphics card the onboard Intel graphics was automatically disabled and so its drivers were never updated ever since.

The solution was enabling multiple video card support in the BIOS (thus re-enabling the integrated graphics card) and **setting the newer PCIe card as primary display output** from the same BIOS screen. Do not forget this, otherwise the system might decide using the less powerful integrated graphics device as primary device.

When the system was rebooted the Intel utilities were able to detect again the hardware and download the updated drivers for it. Once this happened Houdini started up without any problems.

At the following page there's a more in-detail guide on how to re-enable Intel integrated graphics in a multiple video card setup:

https://www.xsplit.com/support/useful-tools/enabling-intel-graphics

Side notes:

1. I am not sure whether the integrated Intel adapter could be disabled again (after the update) and Houdini would still run or not. Anyway I am keeping the integrated device enabled unless I'll notice any problems.
2. I've also quickly skimmed through articles saying that with this setup the system may perform better due to some light-weight graphical tasks being offloaded to the integrated graphical device, but honestly I did not investigate this enough to know if all it takes is just enabling multiple video devices in the BIOS... (if you know more comment on!)